# How do I pull individual conditions using regular expressions?

Tags: c#, regex

I am parsing string that have conditions. At the simplest it's "x < 3". For more complex it can be "((x < 3) || (y > 4)) && (z == 5)". I can pull all this out using the following in C#:

```
string[] condTokens = new Regex(@"([\(\)])").Split(conditionalExpression.Trim());
```

which gives me the expression broken out by tokens - works great.

However... I hit a problem with:

```
"((x < 3) || (y > 4)) && (z == GetNum(x,y))"
```

because "GetNum()" needs to be a single token.

Anything spring to mind on how to craft a regular expression that will handle this?

**Update:** This was marked as too broad but it is a very specific question. In addition @linden2015 provided a very clever solution.

Comment: a regex won't really help you with this.

Comment: If the only tool you have is a hammer, any problem resembles a nail.

Comment: It will be much easier to just iteratorate over the string and manually parse it. Also, I believe there are already libraries to handle this. One of them should allow functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can do it in two steps.

- Step 1: remove unwanted.
- Step 2: use your original pattern.

The pattern `\w+\(.+?\)` matches `getnum(a, b)`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9ZGlLy/1)

Comment: I wrote a parser but that's not a bad idea. A regular expression that identifies any "FUNC(.*)" replacing each with say $func1, $func2 (use weirder name to insure not something that might exist), then do my initial split, and sub back in. Reallt good suggestion.